# Laravel 4: get all registered routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I create helper class

```
    namespace Services\Menu;

    class Item extends AbstactItem {

       public function add($url, $value, $attr, $params) {
            $routes = \Route::getRoutes(); //return always empty
       }

    }
```

How I can get all registered routes in my class?

Comment: How you are using your class ? Can you give an example how do you want to use those routes ?

Comment: Make sure routes are already registered before you call this method.

Comment: I'm use this for build menu. I add item in global.php. How can I know when routes are initialized? When routes.php called...

Comment: Found where routes initializing...in Illuminate\Foundation start.php And routes calls after global. =\

Comment: I think you got it that routes are not initialized when the `global.php` loaded, so need to change the location.

Answer (score 4):

You can see all registered routes by running simple artisan command in your terminal:

```
$ php artisan routes
```

Comment: While true, this has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is something that works fine for me:

```
Route::get('/test', function()
{
    dd( Route::getRoutes() );
});
```

And this too

```
Route::get('routes', array('uses'=>'RoutesController@routes'));

class RoutesController extends BaseController {

    public function routes()
    {
        dd( Route::getRoutes() );
    }

}
```

I understand that this is a problem in your end. Since you're not getting any errors you might, for example, be running this before the routes are built.

**EDIT**

Since I don't really know what's happening, I'm doing tests to see if I can get it behave the way it does in your end.

This one also worked here:

```
Route::get('/test', function() {

    $r = new APP\MyRoutes();

    $r->routes();

});
```

and the class

```
<?php namespace APP;

class MyRoutes {

    public function routes()
    {
        dd( \Route::getRoutes() );
    }

}
```

I also added it to the psr-0 section of my composer.json:

```
"psr-0": {
    "APP": "app/controllers"
}
```

And the class file is located at ´app/controllers/APP/MyController.php´.

Comment: There is already a `getRoutes()` method available but I missed it :p

Comment: this is the same what I'm doing. In controller getRoutes work nice, but in my class it does not work =(

Comment: Edited to add more tests I did here.